# Verizon Samsung Galaxy Tablet SCH-i905 UserAgent string does not say Android

Tags: android, user-agent, galaxy

We have a Samsung Verizon Galaxy tablet, model SCH-i905 4G LTE.  It does not display Android in the userAgent string for the browser.  The device uses Android 3.1.

What it does display is this.
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16

Is this a bad user agent string?  Anybody know if Verizon/Samsung goofed on the build?  It's causing me to have difficulty detecting Android in my Javascript on my website.

Comment: This sounds unbelievable. Pleas double check. Use the tablet to go to http://show-ip.net/useragent/

Comment: That is just the way it is, at least the Xoom, T-Mobile G2, and Motorolla Milestone devices I´ve tested all report that user agent.

You can just go about setting your own.

Now, if you are just talking about people opening the browser, that is the user agent for the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same thing from my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (the one that I got at Google I/O and the one that Samsung wasn't allowed to modify)

Personally, I don't know why Peter K. is so surprised.

The best practice for building web sites is **not** to test by user-agent, but to test by functionality. This way, this allows new hardware and new browsers to get created/modified without getting blocked/misdirected by web sites at their initial inception.

And if Google had really included the keyword "android" in the user-agent of its Honeycomb tablets, you can just imagine that a significant percentage of web sites would have just redirected those tablet browsers to a stripped-down mobile of their web site (without really thinking about it).

And as a 10.1" Honeycomb tablet owner myself, one who also happens to be on 4G, that would have destroyed the entire experience for me. With my large screen size, I certainly don't need to be looking at a stripped-down version of web sites, and with the speed and the latency I have, I actually go way way faster than my personal DSL line.

Comment: What functionality test would you recommend here?

Answer (score 1):

The same UserAgent with my HTC Saga / Desire S Android phone:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16

If you select the Mobile View in the browser configuration. it includes Android and device info:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; es-es; HTC_DesireS_S510eBuild/GRJ90) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1